# Right angle displacement

Tags: displacement, height-map

When using a height map like the one below, what's the best way to displace the mesh so that there is no transition between the light gray and dark gray? No matter how many times you subdivide the mesh, this will not create the desired 90º angle between faces.

[image: height map]

Comment: Height Map does not change the topology of a  surface.  Extrusion of a  subdivided  plane can create vertices of 5 edges from vertices of 4 edges.  So you may want to see extrusion videos where this fact is used to advantage .  Models of humans et cetera have 5 edges corners or 5 poles for arms or legs. Perhaps the majority of edges would have 4 edge corners or 4 poles.  Consider searching extrusion and topology.

Comment: The right angles you seek will come from 5 pole topology or ... simple composition of scaled cubes .. using more vertices and edges than 5 pole topology.

Comment: Lets assume your height map is generated by some texture. Blender has particle systems which can place scaled cubes in particular areas based on the texture data. So you could match scaled cubes to the pixel colors / grey scale values of your texture. Knowing that you may want search differently. You can probably search better than I can. If you are conversant in Python that is an option as well